# Cannot get `Regex::replace()` to replace a numbered capture group

Tags: regex, rust

I'm porting a pluralizer to Rust and I'm having some difficulty with regular expressions. I can't get the `Regex::replace()` method to replace a numbered capture group as I would expect. For example, the following displays an empty string:

```
let re = Regex::new("(m|l)ouse").unwrap();
println!("{}", re.replace("mouse", "$1ice"));
```

I would expect it to print "mice", as it does in JavaScript (or Swift, Python, C# or Go)

```
var re = RegExp("(m|l)ouse")
console.log("mouse".replace(re, "$1ice"))
```

Is there some method I should be using instead of `Regex::replace()`?

Examining the [Inflector crate](https://crates.io/crates/Inflector), I see that it extracts the first capture group and then appends the suffix to the captured text:

```
if let Some(c) = rule.captures(&non_plural_string) {
    if let Some(c) = c.get(1) {
        return format!("{}{}", c.as_str(), replace);
    }
}
```

However, given that `replace` works in every other language I've used regular expressions in, I would expect it work in Rust as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/regex/0.2.2/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace):

> The longest possible name is used. e.g., `$1a` looks up the capture group named `1a` and not the capture group at index `1`. To exert more precise control over the name, use braces, e.g., `${1}a`.

And

> Sometimes the replacement string requires use of curly braces to
>   delineate a capture group replacement and surrounding literal text.
>   For example, if we wanted to join two words together with an
>   underscore:
>
> ```
> let re = Regex::new(r"(?P<first>\w+)\s+(?P<second>\w+)").unwrap();
> let result = re.replace("deep fried", "${first}_$second");
> assert_eq!(result, "deep_fried");
> ```
>
> Without the curly braces, the capture group name `first_` would be used,
>   and since it doesn't exist, it would be replaced with the empty
>   string.

You want `re.replace("mouse", "${1}ice")`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I must've read that section 20 times. That works perfectly! Thank you!