# When replacing with regexes, how do I append digits to the end of a match group?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

This is for Visual Studio code, but I'm not sure how relevant that is.

Here's my regex: `cost:(\d\d)`

I'm trying to multiply that number by 100. e.g., change `cost:25` to `cost:2500`

But if I try this replacement, it thinks I'm asking for group #100, instead of group #1 and two zeros: `cost:$100` changes `cost:25` to `cost:$100`. If I put a space after the two zeros, it replaces it with this: `cost:25 00`. Is there a way to tell the regex engine where the group name stops?

I've tried replacing with `cost:${1}00`, but that doesn't work. It changes it to `cost:${1}00`:

[image]

Comment: Try replacing with `$&00`

Comment: @nhahtdh Nope, it prints literally

Comment: Weird, my suggestion works on the latest version

Comment: @nhahtdh I am on the latest version. Are you sure you're not confusing it for Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope, I'm using VS Code as well 1.51.1

Comment: @nhahtdh that's odd. I checked for updates and it said I was on the latest.

Comment: Interestingly, substitution `cost:$1$'00` works. Although `$'` means [Substituting the Text after the Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @HaoWu: Interestingly, `$'` in replacement gives literal replacement for me. I don't understand what is happening anymore

Comment: @nhahtdh In my case `$100` works as expected without any issue. I'm using `1.52.0-insider` though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [VS Code 1.51.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIDH3.png), this solution works for Replace (current file) and Replace in Files:

- Use `$0` to refer to the whole match:

  Search: `cost:\d\d`

  Replace: `$000`

As mentioned in the comment, these two methods only works for Replace (current file) but not Replace in Files:

- Use `$&` to refer to the whole match:

  Search: `cost:\d\d`

  Replace: `$&00`
- Use `$1` to refer to the first capturing group:

  Search: `cost:(\d\d)`

  Replace: `cost:$100`

  For the regular Replace, the replacement string parsing rule is the same as JavaScript. Since we don't have 10 or 100 capturing groups in the regex, the replacement string is parsed as `$1` (whatever matched in group 1) followed by literal `00`

  However, for Replace in Files, the replacement only works when there is only 1 digit following the `$1` (`cost:$10`). Once there are more than 2 digits, it's treated as literal string replacement

I played around with named capturing groups - while they are recognized in the search field, I can't refer to it in replacement string. Common syntax such as `${group}` and `$<group>` doesn't work.

---

After testing a bit more, I find some weird bugs with how Replace in Files is implemented.

- This straight-forward method with named capturing group doesn't work:

  Search: `cost:(?<n>\d\d)`

  Replace: `cost:$<n>00`

  But we can coax it to work by mixing named capturing group replacement with numbered group replacement:

  Search: `cost:(?<n>\d\d)()`

  Replace: `cost:$2$<n>00`

  We can also apply this trick to get the numbered group replacement to work:

  Search: `cost:(\d\d)()`

  Replace: `cost:$2$100`

  Seems that there is a bug when the replacement string only includes a single replacement token.

Comment: I wish I knew why that first one didn't work for me. I'm on the same version (1.51.1).

Comment: #2 does work for me though. I wish I knew why none of the others didn't.

Comment: What OS are you on? I'm on Windows

Comment: I just put up a screenshot of About screen @DanielKaplan

Comment: #1 works in the Find widget but not Search across Files.  #2 works in Find and Search.  #3 works in the Find widget but not Search across Files.   I presume @nhahtdh tested them in the Find widget but the OP  is using the Search across Files panel instead.

Comment: @Mark That's exactly what I did

Comment: @DanielKaplan Updated with some more testing - so damn buggy

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using groups, why not match the zero-width character using lookbehind?

```
(?<=cost:\d\d)
```

- replacement:

```
00
```

[image]

Comment: That works! I hope you understand, but I don't want to accept this as the answer because it's only contextual that this solution works for me. I'd still like to know how to do what the title says. But have an upvote

Comment: nice +1, you could also use `\d+`

Comment: @DanielKaplan I agree with you, this is only avoiding the problem, not actually solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You have run into this bug discussed here: [VSCode Regex Find/Replace In Files: can't get a numbered capturing group followed by numbers to work out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850149/vscode-regex-find-replace-in-files-cant-get-a-numbered-capturing-group-followe/62851339#62851339)

and the filed issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102221

which was unfortunately closed with "ask on SO response" despite having originated here.  Although there are workarounds - also noted in the So link here, you can still comment on the issue and ask it to be reopened.

The weird thing is that if you add just one digit like `cost:$10` it works just fine - that is why I consider this a bug.